# Powershell Compare Folder and Sub folder names in two directories

Tags: powershell, directory, compare

I have the following to folders:

```
V:\100 Migrering til Dalux\ES 
E:\ES
```

I'd like to compare the folder and sub folder names to make sure they are similar.
I've been trying to get the following code to work without success:

```
$ES = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path E:\ES
$ES = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path V:\100 Migrering til Dalux\ES

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $ES -DifferenceObject $ES
```

Edit:I get the following error:

Get-ChildItem : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'til'.
At line:3 char:7

- $ES = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path V:\100 Migrering til Dalux\ES
- ```
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Comment: What does "without success" look like? Any errors thrown? If so, what do the error messages say?

Comment: You need to quote paths with spaces. `'V:\100 Migrering til Dalux\ES'`

Comment: As @DougMaurer says, but also, you are using the exact same variable for both lists so you are trying to compare a directory list to itself, **AND** is (as the title says) you want to compare only folder names, not files inside these, you should add switch `-Directory` to the Get-ChildItem calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 errors.

1. You have space into your path of directory
2. You use the same variable to compare.

Try something like this :

```
$ES1 = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path "E:\ES"
$ES2 = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path "V:\100 Migrering til Dalux\ES"

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $ES1 -DifferenceObject $ES2
```